# Different behavior of the conditionalPanel, depending on the method of creation

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to develop an app with dynamically creating of tabsetPanel where different plots should be visualized depending on user's choice. When I create conditionalPanel statically it works great. But if I create conditionalPanel  dynamically something is going wrong - not only plots are not displayed but even all conditionalPanels disappearing.

Not interesting, but needed code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(rlist)

data("midwest", package = "ggplot2")
midwest <- midwest %>% 
  select(state, category, percprof, area, poptotal, county)
midwest <- midwest %>% 
  filter(category %in% c("AAR", "LHR", "ALU", "LAR", "HAU"))
categories <- unique(midwest$category)
states <- unique(midwest$state)
max_perc_prof <- max(midwest$percprof)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Midwest analysis")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem(text = "Analysis", tabName = "dcTab", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"))
  )
)
```

Here is body code with example of perfectly working conditional panel

```
body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "dcTab",
      fluidRow(
        box(width = 12, 
          numericInput(inputId = "min_perc_prof", 
                       label = "Minimum percent profession:",
                       min = 0,
                       max = max_perc_prof,
                       value = 2,
                       step = 1
          )
        ),
        conditionalPanel(condition = paste0("input.min_perc_prof", " >= ", 2), 
                         h4("I'm good conditionalPanel"),
                         box(width = 12, background = "blue", height = 300
                             # HERE is NOT a problem with plot     
                            , plotOutput("plt_1", height = 280)
                         )
        )
      ),
      fluidRow(
        uiOutput(outputId = "dynamicContentUI")
      )
    )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header = header,
                    sidebar = sidebar,
                    body = body
)
```

And here is a code on server side:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  database <- reactive({
    req(input$min_perc_prof)
    midwest %>% 
      filter(percprof >= input$min_perc_prof)
  })

  tab_state_names <- reactive({
    unique(database()$state)
  })

  tab_category_names <- reactive({
    res <- list()
    for(i in seq(tab_state_names())){
      current_state <- tab_state_names()[[i]]
      current_data <- database() %>% filter(state == current_state)
      current_categories <- sort(unique(current_data$category))
      res[[ current_state ]] <- current_categories
    }
    res
  })

  # Init Ggplot
  p1 <- ggplot(midwest, aes(x=area, y=poptotal)) + geom_point()

  output$plt_1 <- renderPlot({
    p1
  })

  tab_category_content <- reactive({
    if (is.null(tab_category_names())) return(NULL)

    res_content <- lapply(seq(tab_state_names()), function(current_state){

      if(current_state <= length(tab_category_names())){

        tabnames <- tab_category_names()[[ current_state ]]

        res <- lapply(seq(tabnames), function(current_category){ 

          result_list <- list()

          selInputId <- paste0("county_", current_state, "_", current_category)

          current_data <- database() %>% 
                          filter(state == tab_state_names()[[current_state]]) %>% 
                          filter(category == tab_category_names()[[current_state]][[current_category]])

          county_names <- unique(current_data$county)

          sel_input <- selectInput(inputId = selInputId, 
                                label = "Choose county",
                                choices = county_names
          )

          result_list <- c(result_list, list(sel_input))

          for (current_county in county_names) {

            plot_list <- list()

            current_panel <- conditionalPanel(condition = paste0("input.", selInputId, " === ", "\"", current_county, "\""),
                                              h5(current_county),
                                              box(width = 12, background = "blue", height = 300,
                                                  title = current_county
                                               # HERE is a problem with plot     
                                              #  , plotOutput("plt_1")
                                              )

            )
            result_list <- c(result_list, list(current_panel))
          }
          result_list
        })
        res
      }
    })
    names(res_content) <- tab_state_names()

    res_content
  })

  tab_state_content <- reactive({

    if (is.null(tab_state_names())) return(NULL)

    lapply(tab_state_names(), function(current_state){

      if(!is.null(tab_category_names()[[ current_state ]])){

        tabs <- lapply(seq(tab_category_names()[[ current_state ]]), function(current_category) {
          tabPanel(tab_category_names()[[current_state]][[ current_category ]], tab_category_content()[[current_state]][[ current_category ]])
        })
        args = c(tabs, list(width = 12, id = paste0("tab_cat_in_state_", current_state)))

        do.call(tabBox, args)
      }

    })
  })

  output$dynamicContentUI <- renderUI({
    tabs <- lapply(seq(tab_state_content()), function(current_state) {
      tabPanel(tab_state_names()[[ current_state ]], tab_state_content()[[ current_state ]])
    })
    do.call(tabsetPanel, tabs)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I create a tabsetPanel with dynamic number of tabs. Each of them contains tabBox with dynamic number of tabs. Each of them contains a set of conditionalPanels with condition defined by user choice. Every conditionalPanel should contain a plot and this is an essence of the problem.

A code

```
current_panel <- conditionalPanel(condition = paste0("input.", selInputId, " === ", "\"", current_county, "\""),
   h5(current_county),
   box(width = 12, background = "blue", height = 300,
      title = current_county
      # HERE is a problem with plot     
      #  , plotOutput("plt_1")
   )
)
```

works great - we can see conditionalPanel with empty blue box. But the same code with plotOutput

```
current_panel <- conditionalPanel(condition = paste0("input.", selInputId, " === ", "\"", current_county, "\""),
   h5(current_county),
   box(width = 12,
      background = "blue", height = 300,
      title = current_county
      # HERE is a problem with plot     
      , plotOutput("plt_1")
   )
)
```

has totally wrong result. Because not only plot isn't visible but also blue box and conditional panel.

I generally do not understand what I need to change. Any advice will be very useful.